# Json file syntax validation

Tags: json, validation, go, syntax

The question is how to validate syntax in json file in golang? I know that I can unmarshal slice of bytes and get standard error if I missed comma or brackets. How to get line in file where it happens?

Answer (score 5):

If the error is a syntax error in the input JSON then the error returned from the unmarshal will be a `*json.SyntaxError`:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#SyntaxError

This contains the position in the input byte slice that caused the error as it's Offset field.  To get this you do a type switch to check if it's this type of error and convert it to this type to get the offset value out of it as per the instructions here:

https://tour.golang.org/methods/16

You can then use a bufio Scanner to find the line number:

https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner

Putting this all together you have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

const myJSON = `
{ 
    "totallyValid": "this is OK",
    "missing quotes: not OK
}
`

func main() {
    var result map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJSON), &result)
    switch err := err.(type) {
    case *json.SyntaxError:
        fmt.Printf("Error in input syntax at byte %d: %s\n", err.Offset, err.Error())
        var line int
        var readBytes int64
        for scanner.Scan() {
            // +1 for the \n character
            readBytes += int64(len(scanner.Bytes()) + 1)
            line += 1
            if (readBytes >= err.Offset) {
                fmt.Printf("Error in input syntax on line %d: %s\n", line, err.Error())
                break
            }
        }
    default:
        fmt.Printf("Other error decoding JSON: %s\n", err.Error())
    }
}
```

This is runnable here:

https://play.golang.org/p/aZJF20VfvYm